# Fancybox minimum does not work for video properly?

Tags: fancybox

When using fancybox with an overlay, I seem to have issues with the jQuery working?

View it at mg.hejmej.com/index.html  (2nd box from the left)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are targeting your youtube videos via `embed` mode

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/HGVTaIlzocM
```

then you need the proper fancybox script using `'type':'iframe'`:

```
$("a.fancybox-vidz").fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'         : 680,
            'height'        : 495,
            'type'          : 'iframe',
});
```

You may optimize your link to autoplay and to position itlself behind the fancybox close button like

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HGVTaIlzocM?autoplay=1&amp;wmode=opaque" title="Have a blast at Max's Golf Centre!" class="fancybox-vidz"><img alt="Photo" src="images/h3.jpg" class="fade" style="opacity: 1;"></a>
```