# How to get a iframe in an Image Map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, imagemap

I have been working on the side bar where it says **Click On Game Lists Below** on http://www.bespoke-arcades.co.uk/store/arcade-machines/16-synergy-elite-arcade-machine.html on the left hand side.

I have an image map because I would rather have one image downloaded than a ton (as it slows down loading times).

But the image map won't allow me to use `class="iframe"` in the `<area>` tag. If I do `<a href="xxx" class="iframe"><img src="yyy" /></a>` it will work and open up a fancybox iframe popup, but if I use the imagemap the `class="iframe"` function isn't really accepted.

Is there any work around to making this work? I have the fancybox js and css on the page in question. I also have the correct javascript to work if I use that `class` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.iframe').fancybox();
</script>
```

by this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('area.iframe').fancybox({
        "type":"iframe",
        "width": 600, // or whatever
        "height": 380
    });
});
</script>
```

... of course, don't forget to add `class="iframe"` to each `area` tag.

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9335580/1055987) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418310/1055987) for further reference.